# How to redirect blogger to custom domain without asking user?

Tags: redirect, blogger

I set up a custom domain for blog.

[image]

Problem: when I hit old blog URL, Blogger asks me to confirm redirection to new domain.

[image]

I don't want my readers to say 'Yes' every time, ideally not even once. How to overcome this?

Comment: instead of doing it from the settings, maybe in the template you can add: `<script>location.href = "http://yoursite.com";</script>` just after `<head>`

Comment: Downvoter or whoever voted to close this as 'off-topic' - I already knew it's off topic, see note at the start. Help me find a suitable SE site to post this before closing.

Comment: As the custom domain is not hosted on Blogger, this warning will keep on showing. A much better way would be to unlink the domain from the dashboard & then implement what @mehulmpt suggested. Also, the SE site which would be suited for this question - https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogger

Comment: I didn't do anything, and it's working just fine now.

Comment: Yes, as the domain is now hosted on Blogger platform. Then the warning will go away itself.

Comment: @PrayagVerma I didn't do what @mehulmpt suggested. I still have domain set through settings. I didn't add `<meta>` or `script` for redirection.

Comment: Yes, now that `<meta>` tag is unnecessary. Adding it now will cause a redirect loop. Yesterday, when I opened the URL niksofteng.com, it was not showing a Blogger blog (It was instead showing a custom HTML page). I assumed that you wanted to host the domain outside of Blogger and only wanted to redirect the blog to this domain.

Comment: @halfer - Now that you removed that important note, shall I expect more downvotes?

Comment: You may be stuck either way, to be honest. An opener of "I know this is off-topic but I am going to deliberately create some administration work by asking it anyway" does sometimes result in a slew of DVs. However it's a few days old now, so you seem to have gotten away with it.

Comment: I would probably have asked this on _Super User_. For what it is worth, question migrations seem to be a great deal rarer these days than they were a few years ago. I wonder whether the proposed target site has to accept them? Thus, if you want a question to find a long-term home where it is not closed, it is best to find out if it's on-topic first. I expect you could ask in [SO CVR chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), or in a tech-specific chat room.

Comment: (Aside: I argue that voting commentary and other meta stuff does not belong in posts, which means that posts need to stand or fall on their own merits. We want voting to be organic as well, so requests not to DV, or encouragement to UV, should be removed. Hope that helps.)

Comment: @halfer Thanks for educating me. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not have to do anything. All I did was to wait one day. One day because I checked it the next day. This may not be the exact time required for changes to take effect.

However, if the problem does not go away automatically as in my case, I would like to highlight solutions from couple comments above (because someone once told me many readers don't read comments here on SO).

Comment by @mehulmpt

> instead of doing it from the settings, maybe in the template you can
>   add: location.href = "http://yoursite.com"; just
>   after

Comment by @Prayag Verma

> As the custom domain is not hosted on Blogger, this warning will keep
>   on showing. A much better way would be to unlink the domain from the
>   dashboard & then implement what @mehulmpt suggested. Also, the SE site
>   which would be suited for this question -
>   webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogger